# mapping a list of switches in python

Tags: python, mapping, mininet

I'm writing a mininet topology in python. There is a part in my code that is supposed to map the switches to the controllers. When I write the name of switches and controllers one by one, it's working fine:

```
cmap = {'s0': [c0], 's1': [c1], 's2': [c1]}

class MultiSwitch(OVSSwitch):
    "Custom Switch() subclass that connects to different controllers"
    def start(self, controllers):
        return OVSSwitch.start(self, cmap[self.name])
```

Now imagine I have 2 lists of switches:

```
switchL1 = [s1, s2, s3]
switchL2 = [s4, s5]
```

and I want to use a loop for this mapping instead of writing one by one, So that switches in first list will be connected to one controller and the ones in the second list will be mapped to another controller.

So it should be like this:

```
cmap = {'switchL1': [c0], 'switchL2': [c1]}

class MultiSwitch(OVSSwitch):
    "Custom Switch() subclass that connects to different controllers"
    def start(self, controllers):
        return OVSSwitch.start(self, cmap[self.name])
```

How can I do this? I tried this code:

```
cmap = {'%s': [c0] % (sw1) for sw1 in range(switches_L1), '%s': [c1] % (sw2) for sw2 in range(switches_L2)}
```

but I got `invalid syntax error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. We can use this:

```
switchL1 = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
switchL2 = ['s4', 's5']

cmap1={}
cmap2={}
for sw1 in switchL1:
    cmap1[sw1] = [c0]

for sw2 in switchL2:
    cmap2[sw2] = []

cmap={}
cmap.update(cmap1)
cmap.update(cmap2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats an invalid dictionary comprehension

```
cmap = {
    **{'%s': [c0] % (sw1) for sw1 in range(switches_L1)},
    **{'%s': [c1] % (sw2) for sw2 in range(switches_L2)}
}
```

If you want to create 2 linked dictionaries, create them separately, then unpack them using double asterisk `**` notation into a new dictionary. The format is:

```
newdict = {**dict1, **dict2}
```

Comment: I changed my code to this: `cmap1 = {'%s': [c0] % (sw1) for sw1 in range(switches_L1)}`  
`cmap2 = {'%s': [c1] % (sw2) for sw2 in range(switches_L2)}`  
`cmap = {**cmap1, **cmap2}` but I received this error:     `cmap = {**cmap1, **cmap2}
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I also tried to use your first code but I encountered the same error. It seems to have problem with `**`

Comment: What python version are you using? This seems to be a general method, but it works in `python 3.5+`. (And I'm sure people will agree if you're not using the latest version, you're missing out.) Otherwise you'll have to merge the dictionaries using the `dict.update()` method

Comment: Yes, mine is an older version. Python 2.7.14